# enumerative combinatorics with fixed number repeats

Tags: co.combinatorics

My math skills are a bit rusty, I've run into this problem which is I'm sure a classic variation of combinatorics (please name it if so).

Given a set of N items to choose from, choose R (nCr), but there are a fixed number of repetitions allowed and then no more.  For instance, 6 items (a,b,c,d,e,f), choose 6, 2 repeats allowed:

valid answers:

```
a,a,b,b,c,d
a,a,a,b,b,c
a,b,a,b,a,c   [edit: repeats don't have to be contiguous]
a,a,a,c,b,b   [edit: repeats don't have to be adjacent to each other]
```

invalid:

```
a,a,b,b,c,c
```

not sure (zero or one repeat may be allowed, but I don't know yet):

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
a,a,a,a,a,a
a,a,a,a,b,c
```

Comment: You should try to improve the wording of your question: I don't think this is what most people would call the number of repetitions.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have *n* elements, we want to generate *r* elements (without order), and want exactly *k* elements to be repeated.

We can separate the result into a part containing all the repeated elements (the *repeating* part) and all the rest (the *non-repeating* part). Suppose the repeating part is of length *m*. There are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose the distinct elements in the repeating part. Each of them appears at least twice, and the other *m*−2*k* elements are arbitrary, so can be chosen in $\binom{m-k-1}{k-1}$ ways. There are $\binom{n-k}{r-m}$ possible choices for the non-repeating part.

Putting it all together:

> $\binom{n}{k} \sum_{m=2k}^r \binom{m-k-1}{k-1} \binom{n-k}{r-m}$

If you want to allow less repeating elements, just sum over *k* as well.

Comment: I'm trying to absorb this and it seemed I may not have stated that repeats don't have to be contiguous in the problem, does your solution still hold?

Comment: I think so, you can punch in some numbers and check.